# How to convert in hive a string representation of array of json objects back to array form

Tags: sql, string, hive

I am working in hive / SQL.  I have a column in my table with strings which represent an array of json objects. I need to convert the strings to arrays of JSON strings.

For example, I have this,

```
"[{a:1, b:1},{a:2, b:2}]"
```

And I want to get this:

```
["{a:1, b:1}","{a:2, b:2}"]
```

Tried casting the string as array but that didn't work. Any ideas on how do this in a smart way short of splitting by "},{"?

Answer (score 0):

never mind, I ended up just splitting the string on "}" and then adding back the "}" to each piece, worked well!

Comment: Were you able to do this using Hive's UDFs? If so, could you share the code -- thanks!